# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Не могу установить многие пакеты на python 3.4.

Всё время выдаёт ошибку:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

При этом Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 у меня установлен. Я не очень разбираюсь в тонкостях, может ли это быть связано с тем, что у меня нет прав администратора?
Очень буду признателен за простые советы.

Comment: Скорее всего папку, в которой лежит vcvarsall.bat, нужно добавить в переменную окружения PATH.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно для "чайника" пояснить как это сделать?

Comment: Вы используете `pip`? Попробуйте `easy_install` для тех пакетов, которые ругаются на отсутствие VC++.

Так же тут подробно описано как устанавливать питон под винду:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows

Comment: Да, попробовал через pip easy_install, но всё еще жалуется на отсутствие файла. Ещё идеи?

Answer (score 1):

## Для Visual Studio C++ 2010

[Качаем здесь](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads). Если получится. У меня получилось, но надо быть зарегестрированным клиентом микрософта.

По данным Microsoft, Если вы установили Visual Studio 2010 SP1, возможно, были удалены компиляторы и библиотеки для VC++.
Если это так, скачать [Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422).

Скриншоты от 12 декабря 2018.

[image: Было]

[image: Качаем]

[image: Ставим]

[image: Результат]